# Would a stick be perpendicular to an attached wire in centripetal motion without gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force, angular-velocity

I'm visualizing a system where we have a stick with some non-negligible length attached to a string. The string is attached to a fixed point on the other end, and the stick begins rotating around the fixed point in uniform circular motion.

Now, suppose there are no external forces on the system, namely no gravity. The only force is the centripetal force (in this case, tension).

Would the stick be aligned perpendicular to the string, or would it stay in its original orientation throughout the entire experiment? My intuition tells me that it should be aligned perpendicularly, but this implies there is some external force causing the stick to rotate, right?

Comment: " but this implies there is some external force causing the stick to rotate, right?" You have defined an external force " by "The string is attached to a fixed point on the other end,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your system looks like this:

[image: Stick on string]

So one end of the string is tied to the pivot and the other end is tied to the stick, and the whole system is rotating around the pivot at an angular frequency $\omega$.

In this case there is a tension in the string equal to the centripetal force $mr\omega^2$, and this tension is equal to the force on the pivot. If you imaging whirling the rod around with the string attached to your finger then you'd feel the force on your finger, and that's where the external force is coming from.

The force has a component $T cos(\theta)$ normal to the stick and this will make the stick rotate. The only way the stick won't rotate is if $cos(\theta)=0$ i.e. $\theta = 90°$, and this happens when the stick is aligned with the string. So you are correct that the only stable configuration is with the string and stick in a straight line. The torque on the stick is only zero in this case.

[image: Straight line]

If we start with $\theta \ne 90°$ then the stick would oscillate continuously about its centre of mass as you whirled it round. If there was some friction, e.g. due to air resistance, then the oscillations would die away with time and the stick would end up in line with the string. If there is negligible friction the stick will keep on oscillating as the string and stick rotate about the pivot.